# DAX formula for - Extracting a column value from a table based on certain conditions

Tags: dax

I'm trying extract a column from the table based on certain Conditions:

Here is the scenario:

I have a table `tb1` with `(project_id, month_end_date, monthly_proj_cost)` and table `tb2` with `(project_id, key_member_type, key_member, start_dt_active, end_dt_active).

I would like to extract `key_member where key_member_type="PM"` and active as of `tb1 (month_end_date)`.

Is this possible using DAX?

Thanks,
Satya T

Comment: Is key member a text field? Do you just want the max value?

Answer (score 2):

I like building up measures slowly when developing. You can combine these measures essentially into a single measure if you want, but for instructive purposes, I prefer showing the intermediate steps to achieve the desired DAX goal.

Create a measure to return a single `key_member`. I assume this is text so I used

```
AnyMember :=
LASTNONBLANK ( tb2[key_member], 1 )
```

If it's numeric, you can just use `MAX(tb2[key_member])` instead. It doesn't matter what aggregation you use, since we're only going to return one `key_member` per `project_id`.

Create a measure to filter LastMember so we only return "PM" key_member_types.

```
AnyPM :=
CALCULATE ( [AnyMember], tb2[key_member_type] = "PM" )
```

If you have a continuous date table, create a relationship between your date table and tb2[end_dt_active]. Then create this measure:

```
LastActivePM :=
CALCULATE (
    [AnyPM],
    DATESBETWEEN (
        BasicCalendarEnglish[DateKey],
        MIN ( tb1[month_end_date] ),
        DATE ( 4000, 1, 1 )
    )
)
```

This simply filters out any PMs whose `end_dt_active` comes before the `tb1[month_end_date]`.

Without a date table, to achieve the same filter, you can do:

```
LastActivePM :=
CALCULATE (
    [AnyPM],
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( tb2[end_dt_active] ),
        tb2[end_dt_active] >= MAX ( tb1[month_end_date] )
    )
)
```

Depending on how many rows in your source, the second one can potentially not perform very well, but I'm guessing you're more on the order of hundreds of projects rather than millions.